# free() and mxFree() in MATLAB - freeing memory twice

Tags: matlab, memory-management, free, mex

Good day,
I have the following code which has given me problems for a day already.
I have debugged it, and it works fine until trying to free the memory. The free() function should be called at the end of the execution automatically, so I commented the mxFree() code out, in hope of getting a result. Even if I do that, the program frees the memory twice, like in the case of manually freeing memory - and thus I conclude that it is beyond my control.

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: free(): invalid pointer: 0xad2427a1 ***
```

Is there something I missed?

Note: I have tried some examples of .mex files with memory allocation and they work fine - so the mistake is down below, in my code.

```
/*
Beamforming algorithm
Arguments: xr, yr, zr,
           t, ts, W, U,
       Sdata, NrSensor c, omega_o
Output: S1_sum

S1_sum = beamforming(xr,yr,zr,t,ts,W,U,Sdata,NrSensor,c,omega_o)
*/

#include "mex.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INPUT_ARGS 11
#define OUTPUT_ARGS 1

#define Ar(a, b) Ar[b+a*NrSensor]
#define Ai(a, b) Ai[b+a*NrSensor]
#define V(a, b) V[b+a*len_zr]
#define tau(a, b) tau[b+a*NrSensor]
#define tau_s(a, b) tau_s[b+a*len_zr]
#define tau_r(a, b) tau_r[b+a*NrSensor]
#define w(a, b) w[b+a*len_zr]
#define W(a, b) W[b+a*NrSensor]

#define arg(a, b) arg[b+a*len_zr]
#define newrange(a, b) newrange[b+a*len_zr]
#define oldrange(a, b) oldrange[b+a*len_zr]
#define S1_sum_r(a, b, c) S1_sum_r[c+b*len_xr+a*len_yr*len_xr]
#define S1_sum_i(a, b, c) S1_sum_i[c+b*len_xr+a*len_yr*len_xr]
#define Sdata_r(a, b) Sdata_r[b+a*NrSensor]
#define Sdata_i(a, b) Sdata_i[b+a*NrSensor]
#define S1interpr(a, b) S1interpr[b+a*len_zr]
#define S1interpi(a, b) S1interpi[b+a*len_zr]

#define PI_ 3.141592653

double sinc(double x){
  return sin(PI_*x)/(PI_*x);
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray * plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray * prhs[])
{
  /*
    Declarations
  */
  int xr_, yr_, i, j, m;
  int len_xr, len_yr, len_zr, len_t,
    len_t_, NrSensor, NrSensor_Cen;
  double _t, _i, arg_min, arg_max, norm_factor;
  double start_tau, end_tau, c, omega_o;
  double *xr, *yr, *zr, *t, *ts,
    *Sdata_r, *Sdata_i, *W;
  double *Ar, *Ai, *V, *tau, *tau_r, *tau_s,
    *arg, *U, *w, *t_, *x_r, *x_i, *start_index,
    *newrange, *oldrange, *S1_sum_r, *S1_sum_i,
    *S1interpi, *S1interpr;

  /*
    Checking number of arguments
   */

  if(nrhs != INPUT_ARGS)
    mxErrMsgTxt("Incorrect number of arguments!\n");
  if(nlhs != OUTPUT_ARGS)
    mxErrMsgTxt("Incorrect number of outputs!\n");

  /*
    Reading arguments
   */

  xr = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
  yr = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
  zr = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
  t  = mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
  ts = mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
  W  = mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
  U  = mxGetPr(prhs[6]);
  Sdata_r = mxGetPr(prhs[7]);
  Sdata_i = mxGetPi(prhs[7]);
  NrSensor = (int) mxGetScalar(prhs[8]);
  c = mxGetScalar(prhs[9]);
  omega_o = mxGetScalar(prhs[10]);

  len_xr = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
  len_yr = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
  len_zr = mxGetN(prhs[2]);
  len_t  = mxGetM(prhs[3]);

  /*
    Initialisations
  */
  _t     = 0.0;
  len_t_ = 0;
  NrSensor_Cen = NrSensor/2;
    /*
Space allocation and checking


 */
  arg   = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*len_t);
  Ar    = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*NrSensor);
  Ai    = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*NrSensor);
  V     = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*3);
  tau   = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*NrSensor);
  tau_s = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*3);
  tau_r = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*NrSensor);
  U     = malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
  w     = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*3);
  W     = malloc(sizeof(double)*NrSensor*3);
  ts    = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr);
  t     = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_t);
  t_    = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_t);
  x_r   = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_t);
  x_i   = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_t);

  arg      = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*len_t);
  newrange = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*len_t);
  oldrange = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*len_t);

  S1interpr = malloc(sizeof(double)*NrSensor*len_zr);
  S1interpi = malloc(sizeof(double)*NrSensor*len_zr);
  start_index = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_t);
  /*
    S1_sum_r = mxMalloc(len_xr*len_yr*len_zr);
    S1_sum_i = mxMalloc(len_xr*len_yr*len_zr);
  */

  int dim_S1_sum[3] = {len_xr, len_yr, len_zr};
  plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, dim_S1_sum, 
                 mxDOUBLE_CLASS,
                 mxCOMPLEX);
  S1_sum_r = (double*) mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
  S1_sum_i = (double*) mxGetPi(plhs[0]);

  if(arg   == NULL ||
     Ar    == NULL ||
     Ai    == NULL ||
     V     == NULL ||
     tau   == NULL ||
     tau_s == NULL ||
     tau_r == NULL ||
     U     == NULL ||
     W     == NULL ||
     w     == NULL ||
     ts    == NULL ||
     t     == NULL ||
     t_    == NULL ||
     x_r   == NULL ||
     x_i   == NULL ||
     start_index == NULL ||
     newrange == NULL ||
     oldrange == NULL ||
     S1_sum_r == NULL ||
     S1_sum_i == NULL ||
     S1interpr == NULL||
     S1interpi == NULL){
    mxErrMsgTxt("Malloc error!\n");
    return;
  }


  /*
    --- INITIALISING S1interp, S1_sum, tau, full of zeros
   */

  for(i=0; i<NrSensor; i++){
    for(j=0; j<len_zr; j++){
      S1interpr(i,j) = 0;
      S1interpi(i,j) = 0;
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<len_xr; i++){
    for(j=0; j<len_yr; j++){
      for(m=0; m<len_zr; m++){
    S1_sum_r(i,j,m) = 0;
    S1_sum_i(i,j,m) = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<NrSensor; i++){
    for(j=0; j<len_zr; j++){
    tau(i,j) = 0;
    }
  }

  /*
    --- MAIN ALGORITHM ---
   */
  for(xr_=0; xr_ < len_xr; xr_++){
    for(yr_=0; yr_ < len_yr; yr_++){

      for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
        V(0, i) = xr[xr_];
    V(1, i) = yr[yr_];
    V(2, i) = zr[i];
      }

      for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
    tau_s(0, i) = V(0, i) - U[0];
    tau_s(1, i) = V(1, i) - U[1];
    tau_s(2, i) = V(2, i) - U[2];
      }

      for(m=0; m < NrSensor; m++){
    for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
      /*
        I see no point of the squeeze function
        since W is already of known sizes
      */
      w(0, i) = V(0, i) - W(0, m);
      w(1, i) = V(1, i) - W(1, m);
      w(2, i) = V(2, i) - W(2, m);
    }

    for(i=0; i< len_zr; i++){
      /*
        sum(w.*w)
      */
      _t = w(0, i)*w(0,i) +
        w(1, i)*w(1,i) +
        w(2, i)*w(2,i);

      tau_r(m, i) = sqrt(_t)/c;
    }
      }

      for(m=0; m < len_zr; m++){
    for(i=0; i < NrSensor; i++){
      /*
        Computing sum(tau_s(m, :).*tau_s(m, :))
      */
      _t = tau_s(0, m)*tau_s(0, m) +
        tau_s(1, m)*tau_s(1, m) +
        tau_s(2, m)*tau_s(2, m);

      tau(i, m) = tau_r(i, m) + sqrt(_t)/c;
    }
      }

      /*
    for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
    for(j=0; j < NrSensor; j++){
    Tau(i,j)=tau(i,j);
    }
    }
      */

      for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
    for(j=0; j < NrSensor; j++){
      Ar(i,j)=cos(omega_o * tau(i, j));
      Ai(i,j)=sin(omega_o * tau(i, j));
    }
      }

      /*
    --- BIG LOOP AHEAD ---
       */
      for(m=0; m < NrSensor; m++){
    start_tau = tau(NrSensor_Cen, 1);
    end_tau = tau(NrSensor_Cen, len_zr);

    /*
      Finding index : writing start indexes
      and also t_ array
    */
    len_t_=0;

    for(i=0; i<len_t; i++){
      if(t[i] >= start_tau &&
         t[i] <= end_tau){
        start_index[len_t_] = i;
        t_[len_t_] = t[i];
        x_r[len_t_] = Sdata_r(i, m);
        x_i[len_t_] = Sdata_i(i, m);
        len_t_++;
      }
    }

    for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
      ts[i]=tau(m, i);
    }

    for(i=0; i < len_t_; i++){
      for(j=0; j < len_zr; j++){
        newrange(i, j) = ts[j];
      }
    }

    for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
      for(j=0; j < len_t_; j++){
        oldrange(j, i) = t_[j];
      }
    }

    for(i=0; i < len_t_; i++){
      for(j=0; j < len_zr; j++){
        arg(i, j) = newrange(i, j)-oldrange(i, j);
      }
    }

    arg_min = arg[0];
    for(i=0; i < len_t_; i++)
      for(j=0; j < len_zr; j++)
        if(arg_min>arg(i, j))
          arg_min=arg(i, j);

    arg_max = arg[0];
    for(i=0; i < len_t_; i++)
      for(j=0; j < len_zr; j++)
        if(arg_max<arg(i, j))
          arg_max=arg(i, j);


    norm_factor = (2*len_t_)/(arg_max-arg_min);

    for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
      _t = 0; 
      for(j=0; j < NrSensor; j++){
        _t = sinc(arg(i, j)*norm_factor)*x_r[j];
      }

      S1interpr(m, i) = Ar(m, i) * _t;

      _t = 0; 
      for(j=0; j < NrSensor; j++){
        _t = sinc(arg(i, j)*norm_factor)*x_i[j];
      }

      S1interpi(m, i) = Ai(m, i) * _t;
    }
      }

      for(i=0; i < len_zr; i++){
    _t = 0;
    for(j=0; j < NrSensor; j++){
      _t += S1interpr(j, i);
    }

    S1_sum_r(xr_, yr_, i) = _t;

    _t = 0;
    for(j=0; j < NrSensor; j++){
      _t += S1interpi(j, i);
    }

    S1_sum_i(xr_, yr_, i) = _t;
      }

    }
  }

  free(arg);
  free(Ar);  
  free(Ai);
  free(V);   
  free(tau); 
  free(tau_s);
  free(tau_r);
  free(U);   
  free(w);   
  free(W);   
  free(ts); 
  free(t);     
  free(t_);   
  free(x_r);   
  free(x_i);   

  free(newrange); 
  free(oldrange);

  free(S1interpr);
  free(S1interpi);
  free(start_index);
  return;
}
```

**EDIT**

I have deleted all my code except the beginning (up to the memory allocation) and the memory freeing. I'm also using malloc() and free() now. In between the memory allocation and freeing, I have also put this code:

```
  for(i=0; i<NrSensor; i++){
    for(j=0; j<len_zr; j++){
      S1interpr(i,j) = 0;
      S1interpi(i,j) = 0;
    }
  }


  for(i=0; i<NrSensor; i++){
    for(j=0; j<len_zr; j++){
    tau(i,j) = 0;
    }
  }
```

The first loop causes no problem. The second one though, apparently corrupts the variable V (declared before it) and the one declared after it. And it seems, according to my logic, that it does not exceed any kind of bounds...

Comment: It could be because of a memory overwrite too. I would try removing pieces of code until the smallest piece reproduces the problem. That would help greatly to diagnose the issue.

Comment: For x,y,z = a,b,c the code `S1_sum_r[c+b*len_xr+a*len_yr*len_xr]`  seems wrong.  BTW, you can just use `malloc` or `new` if you dont plan to pass the memory over after exec.

Comment: @chappjc That apparently is correct, I've tested it. Thank you for the malloc and free advice, I want to be sure I use C functions, not matlab ones. I've edited my post with new information.

Comment: @Navan Thank you, just did that - I've added new information to the post. The first loop works fine, the second doesn't and corrupts variables next to it.

Comment: I still think that indexing is incorrect.  Also keep in mind that the dimensions argument for `mxCreateNumericArray` is not x,y,... (cols,rows,...) it is rows,cols,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop does not index correctly for tau. You are defining indexing for tau as

```
 #define tau(a, b) tau[b+a*NrSensor]
```

Let us walk through the second loop assuming NrSensor = 10 and len_zr = 5. For this case max value of loop variable i is 9 and max value of loop variable j is 4. Now,

```
tau(9,4) => tau[4+9*10] => tau[94].
```

But you are allocating tau with

```
tau   = malloc(sizeof(double)*len_zr*NrSensor);
```

which for the sample values 10 and 5 is

```
tau   = malloc(sizeof(double)*50)
```

You either need to change the indexing definition for tau to swap a and b or change the order of loops i and j.

Comment: That is correct. It is weird seeing the segfault pop-up when freeing the memory, not when exceeding bounds. Indeed I should have been more careful with matrices, because now it is backfiring. Thank you.